# File not found in Docker Container using GitLab-CI

Tags: bash, docker, permissions, echo, gitlab-ci

Using GitLab-CI, I am attempting to echo a secret variable into a file inside a Docker container. The file exists and the user has permissions to write to the file yet I get a `No such file or directory` error.

```
$ /usr/bin/docker exec -t $CI_PROJECT_NAME ls -la /opt/application/conf/kubeadminaccount.yml
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 nodeuser nodeuser 420 Aug 18 07:19 /opt/application/conf/kubeadminaccount.yml

$ /usr/bin/docker exec -t $CI_PROJECT_NAME whoami
    nodeuser

$ /usr/bin/docker exec -t $CI_PROJECT_NAME echo $KUBE_ADMIN_ACCOUNT > /opt/application/conf/kubeadminaccount.yml
    bash: line 69: /opt/application/conf/kubeadminaccount.yml: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can u please upload the dockerfile or yaml file whichever u used to up the conatiner

Comment: Try enclosing the complete echo redirect in quotes and so "echo $KUBE_ADMIN_ACCOUNT > /opt/application/conf/kubeadminaccount.yml"

Comment: I would update the way you create the container instead of trying to update it while it's running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirection operator is working on host and not inside your container. Change below

```
$ /usr/bin/docker exec -t $CI_PROJECT_NAME echo $KUBE_ADMIN_ACCOUNT > /opt/application/conf/kubeadminaccount.yml
```

to

```
$ /usr/bin/docker exec -t $CI_PROJECT_NAME bash -c "echo $KUBE_ADMIN_ACCOUNT > /opt/application/conf/kubeadminaccount.yml"
```

Comment: Had to add `\"` around the variable because of the complex value.

Comment: Yes that would be needed if value has new lines. But rest now things work for you?