# File not found in Gitlab-CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I've already seen this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751331/file-not-found-in-docker-container-using-gitlab-ci) here, but the solution isn't working for a Flutter project I'm working on.

Here's my yaml file:

```
image: cirrusci/flutter

variables:
before_script:
  - flutter channel beta
  - flutter upgrade
  
stages:
#  - build
  - test

#build:
#  stage: build
#  script:
#    - flutter build apk


unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
   # - ls -la /opt/application/
   # - ls -la ~/
    - bash -c "echo \"$APP_VARS\" > ./cfg/env.json"
    - flutter test test/widget_test.dart
```

Which yielded a `cannot access <filename/directory>: File or Directory Not Found` error with both `ls -la /opt/application/` and `bash -c "echo \"$APP_VARS\" > ./cfg/env.json"`

Her's the output from `ls -la ~/`:

```
$ ls -la ~/
total 72
drwxr-xr-x. 1 cirrus cirrus 4096 Jul  9 19:16 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root   root   4096 Mar  7  2018 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 1 cirrus cirrus 4096 Jul  9 19:17 .android
-rw-r--r--. 1 cirrus cirrus  220 May 15  2017 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 cirrus cirrus 3526 May 15  2017 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--. 1 cirrus cirrus   24 Jul  9 19:16 .flutter
-rw-r--r--. 1 cirrus cirrus  675 May 15  2017 .profile
drwxr-xr-x. 1 cirrus cirrus 4096 Jul  9 19:16 .pub-cache
drwxr-xr-x. 1 cirrus cirrus 4096 Jul  9 19:16 sdks
```

My intent is to inject environment variables via the CI for use during testing (and hopefully deployment, although I haven't gotten that far yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is two-part:

First, the `/builds/**/cfg/` directory actually didn't exist. To fix this, you have two options-- do a `mkdir` or commit/push a file in the repo. I added an empty `.gitignore` to my `cfg` directory.

Then, that yielded a `Permission Denied` error. To solve this, I first tried to `sudo` my commands (which let me perform the `mkdir` mentioned above). When that didn't work, I did a `chmod -R 777 /builds/`, and that fixed my issue.

Going forward, I plan to use `chmod [-R] 644` or `chmod [-R] 755` instead and do a `chmod +x` on any files I need to run via a shell script.

I also moved my environment configuration script to the `before_script:` section in the gitlab YAML, but I don't believe that was necessary.

[See](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdb) for info on `chmod`.